# Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 for generated web services in maven

Tags: java, maven, wsgen, jaxws-maven-plugin

I've already done the research to know that this error means "I compiled with a newer version of java than I'm running the code on".  The difference here is that this code that's giving me the error is generated by the [jaxws-maven-plugin](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/) plugin.  I can't figure out how to set the compile target/source on that plugin so I don't know how to resolve this issue.  How do I set the target version for this plugin?

Comment: Why are you deploying to a Java 5 runtime? Even the official Java 6 is EOL now.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis interesting... so it only generates source?

Comment: @chrylis I *believe* I'm deploying to a 1.6 environment.  I'm assuming that I'm compiling using 1.7, though.

Comment: @tieTYT Sorry, got my numbers for 6 and 7 confused.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The `wsimport` goal runs during `generate-sources`, but the `wsgen` runs during `process-classes`, and the options for the goal indicate that by default it generates and immediately compiles its output classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The usage page](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/usage.html) seems to indicate that the JAX-WS plugin uses the standard `source` and `target` settings from `maven-compiler-plugin`.

Comment: This didn't solve *my* problem but it will probably help anyone else searching.  I had a PEBCAK issue.  My IDE was set to compile to 1.7 without my intention.